# Makefile make the objects but won't run the file

Tags: c, makefile, clang

I Have 3 files: main.c lists.c lists.h
main.c includes lists.h
i want to make a makefile, i run it from the terminal but it seems like it only creates the objects and doesn't run them.
What am i doing wrong? 
(Sorry if it seems like a retarded question):

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall

maman21: main.o lists.o

main.o:  main.c

lists.o: lists.c lists.h
```

Comment: What does it mean "to run an object"?

Comment: a `Makefile` won't *run* a program, it is *building* it (the last step should link the object files into an executable).

Comment: What do you mean by "un the file"? Please put more care into writing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules compiles and links the maman21 executable. You can run it manually after it succeeded with the command `./mman21`

If you want the makefile to run the program when it's compiled, make a rule for that,

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall

runit: maman21
     ./maman21

maman21: main.o lists.o
```

...

Note that the line after the runit: rule must be indented by 1 tab character.